# Getting resource with ResourcePatternResolver in Spring Boot return 0 resource with pattern

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Hi I'm trying to get a list of xml file (username_date.xml)

this is my code :

```
    Resource[] resources ;
    ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
    String path = "file:I:/xxxx/yyyy/zzz/Logon history/BBB/username_*.xml";
    try {
        resources = resolver.getResources(path);
        for (Resource resource: resources){
            logger.info(resource.getFilename());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.toString());
    }
```

With this pattern , the server is working for ever and never get any results... 
I'm using Spring Boot 1.4
What did I do wrong ?

Thanks !

Edit :
I waited and 8 min after the request was succesful , any idea why the blank cause this problem ?